# Is there a way to connect AWS Glue to a MySQL table in an Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I know that AWS Glue can connect to an [Amazon RDS with a MySQL Database engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy9Gd.png). However, I want to use Glue extract data files from S3, transform them, and then load them to a specific MySQL *table* rather than loading the data into the entire database. Is there a way that this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use ( scala | python ) + spark for Glue ETL job, look like you can just flush a transformed dataframe to the database. Something like [this](https://medium.com/spark-experts/save-apache-spark-dataframe-to-database-7d6f80e38f53)